# Can I get a Colombian passport in Bogotá, and how long does it take?

Tags: air-travel, passports, colombian-citizens, bogota

I am 24 and was born in Colombia. I left when I was 8 and this is my first visit to Colombia in 16 years.

I have a Canadian passport and entered Colombia without a problem. Once it was time for me to leave they rejected my passport and told me I was required to have a Colombian passport in order to leave since I was born in Colombia. I heard that if you go directly to the passport office in Bogotá with all the needed paperwork you are able to get your passport within a day or two. Is it possible? I need to get home soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Colombian government](http://www.cancilleria.gov.co/en/procedures_services/passports), you can get a passport from the Ministry of Foreign Affairs located in Bogotá or even one of its regional offices.

It doesn't look like it should take too long. According to the same source, the processing time is 24 hours in Bogotá and 48 hours in the regional offices. This is the time from after you have submitted a complete application with payment to when you receive your passport.

<sup>Side note: It looks like (from the same source) that it's not strictly the fact that you were *born* in Colombia that forces you to do this, it's the fact that you (apparently) still have Colombian citizenship. So apparently, if you wanted to travel on your Canadian passport, you would have to renounce your Colombian citizenship. It's probably better to just get the passport and remain a dual citizen.</sup>

Comment: okay so i have a flight back home on August 25th. You think ill be able to get everything handled by then?

Comment: Just apply today (Monday) or at least ASAP and that's all you can do. If you are unsure of anything, ask for help. Make sure you get everything about the application right.

Comment: so it is possible to get it all done!! awesome thank you so much!!!

Comment: @joanne Sure :) Good luck!

Comment: @joanne next time, if you return to Colombia after another 16 years and your Colombian passport has expired, you may want to get one in Canada before your trip, by applying at a Colombian consulate.