# Do I need a Colombian passport?

Tags: us-citizens, colombia, colombian-citizens

So my mom told me recently that she got papers for me to be a Colombian citizen but the thing is, I’ve never been to colombia before. She was supposed to get a passport for me but because of the pandemic, it was delayed and now she’s forcing me to do it. The papers are old and outdated though since she provided papers for me at 8 years old. I’m 20 now. My trip is on December 26th and I don’t know if the Colombian passport will come in time. Do I actually need one? I am a U.S. citizen. Never left the country yet.

Comment: Do you have a US passport?  If you don't have a passport of any kind then it's pretty unlikely that you can make the trip.

Comment: Yeah I have a U.S. passport

Comment: Are you going to Colombia or to some other country?

Comment: I’ll be going go colombia. Only staying for three weeks.

Answer (score 5):

[According to the US Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Colombia.html#:%7E:text=All%20Colombian%20citizens%E2%80%94regardless%20of,they%20obtain%20a%20Colombian%20passport.), yes, you will need both your US passport and your Colombian passport to make this trip:

> All Colombian citizens—regardless of dual citizenship—MUST present a valid, non-expired Colombian passport to enter and exit Colombia.  Colombian citizens traveling with non-Colombian passports may be unable to depart the country until they obtain a Colombian passport.
>
> Be aware that any person born in Colombia or of Colombian parentage may be considered a Colombian citizen, even if never documented as such.
>
> Be aware as well that all U.S. citizens, regardless of dual citizenship, must present a valid U.S. passport upon returning to the United States.  Persons who are both U.S. and Colombian citizens MUST travel between these countries with both passports, presenting the Colombian passport upon departing Colombia and the U.S. passport upon arrival in the United States.

US consular information like this is generally written reactively after other people in similar situations have had a problem, (as has, for example, [this previous Stack Exchange questioner](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77106/can-i-get-a-colombian-passport-in-bogot%c3%a1-and-how-long-does-it-take)) so I would take the warning seriously in your situation — it sounds like you do not want to get stuck in Colombia waiting for a new passport if you can avoid it. Get the paperwork done beforehand, so you can enjoy your trip!